# More advanced search with SourceGraph

Tags: sourcegraph

I am trying to create a query that states the following:

> Find me repos that have file 'baz', which contain 'foo', and also contain file 'bar'.

What I have now doesn't include the second part:

```
file:baz foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query can't be expressed in the current query syntax, which was designed primarily for finding text/regex matches in code.

However, we're expanding search to cover more advanced queries, so I've filed an issue here for this feature: https://github.com/sourcegraph/issues/issues/127. Thanks for using Sourcegraph and feel free to comment on the issue with more context about your use case :)

Comment: Awesome! I'd appreciate if you add this to update this answer :)

Comment: Will definitely do that!